# How to get Acces to make a SNMP set query? ((No access) exception )

Tags: java, exception, snmp, snmp4j

I am trying to make snmp set query in java to a Linux machine, whenever I make the query I get

```
 No Access to 127.0.0.1 6 (No access)</exception>
```

I am really curious about why I can not have an access, do I need to be root to make snmp set query ? Or if you know how I can access to localhost to make this query , can you please help me ?

By the way my Variable consists of 1.3.6.1.4.1 and sysDescr

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every SNMP agent has an address book of all its objects, called the **MIB** or Management Information Base. The MIB provides the name, OID, data type, **read/write permissions**, and a brief description for each object in an SNMP agent. So, if the OID is of read-only, then you can't update value of that OID and **sysDescr** OID is read-only.
For example, [see here.](http://ipmsupport.solarwinds.com/mibs/SNMPV2-MIB/item.aspx?id=sysDescr)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please give me a variable and oid to make a set test ?

Comment: sysContact,sysName, sysLocation are read-write field. Also you can browse all MIBs using the link in answer.